# How can you view only specific users created by a particular user, and not any other info?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, controls

i have posted important code snippets. there are no errors in this. but the thing is that it displays all created users. i want the viewer to show users only created by the registered user.but also if another user is added, even he can login using his credentials like eg: if A has been registered using register option of my code, it then opens a dashboard which has options to logout or add another user. after the another user 'B' is added, it redirects me to a list which shows both the users which have been made. ie: A and B. but now if i log out and login using 'B' credentials, it logs in and in the view section it is showing all users created by A also and B also. but if i log in with A i want the server to display only users that have been added by A. i know i have typed too much and maybe complicated half of the readers of my question, but i'm trying my level best to explain my dilemma

```js
users.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user');

//Register
router.get('/register', function(req, res){
 res.render('register');
});

//Login
router.get('/login', function(req, res){
 res.render('login');
});

//register user
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
 var name = req.body.name;
 var username = req.body.username;
 var email = req.body.email;
 var password = req.body.password;
 var password2 = req.body.password2;

  //validation
   req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
   req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
   req.checkBody('email', 'Email is NOT valid').isEmail();
   req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
   req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
   req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords DO NOT match!').equals(req.body.password);

   var errors = req.validationErrors();

   if(errors){
    res.render('register',{
     errors: errors
    });
   } else {
    var newUser = new User({
     name: name,
     email: email,
     username: username,
     password: password
    });

    User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
     if(err) throw err;
     console.log(user);
    });

    req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now log in!');

    res.redirect('/users/login');
   }
});

router.post('/addOrEdit', function(req, res){
  var name = req.body.name;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var password2 = req.body.password2;

  //validation
    req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is NOT valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords DO NOT match!').equals(req.body.password);


    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
      res.render('addOrEdit',{
        errors: errors
      });
    } else {
      var newUser = new User({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password
      });

      User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
      });

      req.flash('success_msg', 'User created and can now be used for logins!');

      res.redirect('/users/list');
    }
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
   User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user){
     return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
     if(err) throw err;
     if(isMatch){
      return done(null, user);
     } else {
      return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
     }
    });
   });
  }));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

router.post('/login',
 passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:'/', failureRedirect:'/users/login', failureFlash: true}),
 function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/');
 });

router.get('/addOrEdit', (req, res) => {
    res.render("addOrEdit",{
        viewTitle: "Insert User"
    });
});


router.get('/list', (req, res) => {
    User.find((err, docs) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.render('list', {
                list: docs
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('Error in retrieving user list :' + err);
        }
    });
});

router.post('/list', (req, res) => {
    User.find((err, docs) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.render('list', {
                list: docs
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('Error in retrieving user list :' + err);
        }
    });
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    User.findById(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.render("addOrEdit", {
                viewTitle: "Update User",
                employee: doc
            });
        }
    });
});

router.get('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
    User.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.redirect('/users/list');
        }
        else { console.log('Error in user delete :' + err); }
    });
});


router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
 req.logout();
 req.flash('success_msg', 'You Have Logged Out');

 res.redirect('/users/login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

```html
Register.handlebars
<h2 class="page-header">Account Register</h2>
{{#if errors}}
 {{#each errors}}
 <div class="alert alert-danger">{{msg}}</div>
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
<form method="post" action="/users/register">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>E-mail ID</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Confirm Password</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" Re-enter Password" name="password2">
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-grey">Submit</button>
</form>




addoredit.handlebars
<h3>{{viewTitle}}</h3>
{{#if errors}}
    {{#each errors}}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{msg}}</div>
        {{/each}}
{{/if}}


<form action="/users/addOrEdit" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="_id" value="{{user._id}}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>E-mail ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Re-enter Password" name="password2">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-database"></i> Submit</button>
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/users/list"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> View All</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
user.js(schema)
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var db = mongoose.connection;

//User schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 username:{
  type: String,
  index: true
 },
 password:{
  type: String
 },
 email:{
  type: String,
  index: true
 },
 name:{
  type: String,
  index: true
 }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
 bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
  console.log(newUser);
      bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
       newUser.password = hash;
       newUser.save(callback); 
            });
 });
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername= function(username, callback){
 var query = {username: username};
 User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById= function(id, callback){
 User.findById(id, callback);
}


module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
 bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
  if(err) throw err;
  callback(null, isMatch);
 });
}

app.js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStratergy = require('passport-local').Stratergy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Experiment-1', { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err)=>{
     if (!err) { console.log('MongoDB Connection Succeeded.') }
    else { console.log('Error in DB connection : ' + err) }
});
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
//init app
var app = express();

//view engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars',exphbs({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

//bodyParser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Express Session middleware
app.use(session({
 secret: 'secret',
 saveUninitialized: true,
 resave: true
}));

//passport init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Express validator
app.use(expressValidator({
 errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
  var namespace = param.split('.')
  , root = namespace.shift()
  , formParam = root;
 
 while(namespace.length) {
  formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
   }
 return {
     param : formParam,
     msg   : msg,
     value : value
   };
 }
}));

//connect flash
app.use(flash());

//global Vars
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
 res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
 res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
 res.locals.user = req.user || null;
 next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);


//set port
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 7070));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
 console.log('Server started at PORT '+app.get('port'));
});
```

I am creating an app which registers users and then lets them log in and view the dashboard. i am using express, mongod and passport(for user authentication). what i want is that when a user is registered and he logs in, he can view the data of additional users that he has created. the additional created user can also log in to the page, and then he can create more users which can only be viewed by him and not any other user. is this possible?

Comment: HI @Vedant Agarwal. When you create a user, you maintain the one field in mongodb. created_by. who is creating the user. then querying based on this. one.

Comment: hey @krbalaji thanks a lot. i'll try using this, but how do i define wh has reated the user, because my initial register page and the user creation register page which i access after logging in is the same

Comment: Are you storing token upon register or login?

Comment: @iramAkhtar i didnt understand you

Comment: If you are using token like JsonWebToken (JWT) in your application, it will be easy to track the user. But if you are not using anything like this, upon successful register or login, your server can send response with the Id of that particular user. With that Id you can send the request to your server to show only particular records limited to that user only.

Comment: no i am not using jsonwebtokens in my app @IramAkhtar. i am unable to send the response with the id of the user to the server. alsoo, all the fields that i have created in the register section of the code is same as what is in the inside code which adds a new user. so i can; understand how to pass on the id as a unique field and then use that for all users creation by the registered user.